# CUDA compiling error

Tags: cuda

Can anyone please tell me what to do for the following error?

```
1>Linking...
1>.\Debug\CUDA1.cu.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

1>test - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure everything is being set to either 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) compilation. You've got some modules building for the wrong architecture.